# how to download a file from a http server

Tags: http, blackberry, java-me

My app needs to download  a file(.ashx file) from http server.I wrote following function for this.But it takes a lot of time to execute it,andwhen I print it size its more than 30,000. But its only 28 kb.

```
public byte[] downloadFile(String url){
StreamConnection streamConnection=null;
InputStream inputStream=null;
InputStream ips;
byte[] plyListFiles=null;

try {

    HttpConnection httpConnection=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE);
    httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
    int httpStatus=httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    if(httpStatus==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){

        inputStream = httpConnection.openInputStream();
        ips=inputStream;
        plyListFiles= IOUtilities.streamToBytes(ips);


    }
} catch (IOException e) {           
    System.out.println(e);
}
return plyListFiles;
}
```

When I try to return string some junk value is shown.
How can I download a file from a server and write it to our phone.Does any one have idea please help.

Comment: Please don't tell me `plyListFiles` is an abbreviation for `playListFiles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your file size is same I guess 30,000byte/1024 = almost 28kb.

Second, you are not returning string, you are returning bytes. So if you expect to see human readable string from those bytes it seems like junk.

Try using

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(httpConnecton.getInputStream()));
 while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        buff.append(str);
 }
 return buff.toString();
```